# Embeded Firebird permissions problem under Local System Account

Tags: firebird, firebird-embedded

I am creating a NTService Application which use an Embeded Firebird database. When i configure the service run as Administrator account, It works ok. But when i run service as default Local System Account, I get below error.

no permission for read/select access to TABLE XXXX

Why is that ? I belive there is no system tables or etc in Firebird single sql file. And Windows xp dont have linux like file permissions. Please help.

Regards

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the embedded version doesn't authenticate users (doesn't check the username and password against security2.fdb) it still checks the SQL privileges of the user. This means that you still have to grant proper user rights to the username and/or role you're using when accessing the database. It probably worked for the Administrator account because in version 2.1, members of administrative Windows groups were mapped to SYSDBA by default (and thus had all rights on all databases). This changed in version 2.5, you now have to manually configure this (see [release notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes25.html#rnfb25-security)).

Comment: Thanks so much, it really helped. I was connecting to database without any username, When i specified to connect as user sysdba, It works ok now under "Local System Account". Thanks again